# Structure of Pairs inside a Cat Cable

Tags: ethernet, cables, twisted-pair

Is there a standard arrangement for the pairs inside a Cat7|6|5 Ethernet Cable?

As shown in the picture, they are in the sequence Orange-Green-Brown-Blue, or the Orange Brown always as opposite pairs, but I have not reach any solid confirmation for this; even, I have found contradictory sketchs, some with Orange-Brown as opposite pairs as here, others as close pairs.

If positive, the cross bone structure in Cat6 should kept that arrangement in a Cat7|6, but should one expect that arrangement to be kept in a Cat5, where no structure is between the pairs?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Cat7 Cable]

Comment: If they can't capitalise 'OFC' correctly I can't be sure that they have not  coloured that image at random:  that copper sure doesn't look tin-plated.

Comment: Nevertheless the 3D sketch looks pretty decent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 'structure' between the pairs in the cable.

What you can guarantee is that white/x will be twisted with x/white.

Isolation between the pairs is enhanced by giving each pair a different number of twists per unit length. This avoids the stray electromagnetic coupling between pairs growing as the length grows.

Comment: Is the number of twists per unit length related to the colour of each pair?

Comment: Maybe, for any given manufacturer it would make sense. But AFAIK, there is no standard that relates colour to twists.

Comment: you can't guarante white/x - x/white there is a (rare) 8-colour option

Comment: twiste mat vary along the length of the wire, or be constant and different for each pair. doing it lengthwise reduces skew on long runs.